# Write to unmounted usb from terminal

Tags: backup, tty

Here is the problem:
My hard drive bugged I got a load of io errors and my elementary os won't load, I can only load it in read-only console mode.

Question 1 how do I copy important files to a usb drive if I can't mount it? Or how do I restart system  in a readwrite mode

Question 2 how do I check hard drive for bugs and fix them?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take the drive and install it as an extra drive in a working system, mount and "repair" the filesystem there, then copy everything to a new drive or USB stick.

You don't want to be actively using the disk when it's in a bad state.  The general operation of the OS could cause further damage to the filesystem.